# Where can I ask my question on the use of the terms EKG or ECG?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where should I ask my question:

> I have long wondered why doctors use EKG and ECG seemingly interchangeably for for an electrocardiogram. ECG makes sense but EKG always confused me and I discovered that EKG is acronym for the German word for electrocardiogram. I am wondering why is the most commonly used expression for this medical test in German?

I'm unsure where to ask this question as is relates to medicine and language, but I don't think it would be on-topic on *[Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour)* or *[Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/tour)*.

Comment: ([A dictionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/EKG#Etymology).)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems appropriate for the English Language & Usage site, where it has in fact already been asked: [Why is electrocardiogram abbreviated EKG instead of ECG?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/553369/315609)